# How to fix responsive size masonry

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple CSS masonry and when I reduce screen size the second block (`item2`) is too small in size. How to change size of blocks to full width with media query or without?

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.grid-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #929796;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #424242;
}

.big {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
    <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item big">item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 8</div>
    <div class="grid-item big">item 9</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 10</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 11</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 12</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 13</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 14</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 15</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 16</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 17</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 18</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 19</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 20</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 21</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 22</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 23</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when the screen width is not able to hold two columns, you see this issue... so with media query you want to drop the second column below the first one?

Comment: no, i want only all items display full width responsive.

Comment: The issue is that the *grid layout* is over-constrained:

- on one hand the available width is less that that to hold two columns of 180px each (because you have set your columns as `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr))`) - the second `item` want to drop to the next row;

- on the other hand, the third `.item.big` in the second row *spans* two columns which forces the layout to hold a second column.

Comment: i don't understant sorry. How to fix that?

Comment: you can use a media query, see the answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the *grid layout* is over-constrained as per my comments above:

- on one hand the available width is less that that to hold two columns of 180px each (because you have set your columns as `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr))`) - the second `item` want to drop to the next row;
- on the other hand, the third `.item.big` in the second row *spans* two columns which forces the layout to hold a second column.

And you have the issue below ~425px and thereabouts - if you want to target this *screen* you can try a *media query* to adjust your `big` elements to *span* only the first column in small screen widths - see demo below:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.grid-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #929796;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #424242;
}

.big {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) { /* added */
  .big {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
    <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item big">item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 8</div>
    <div class="grid-item big">item 9</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 10</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 11</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 12</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 13</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 14</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 15</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 16</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 17</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 18</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 19</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 20</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 21</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 22</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 23</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Big Thank You! I have another question: Can i show div first of another divs when i add class "sticky" ? How i can do that?

Comment: Yes, for now 'sticky' class isn't exist. But how i can do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you, perhaps you can post another question with a minimal & verifiable snippet?

Comment: I want when i add class "sticky" to div, this div is first in order list

Comment: add `grid-row: 1` and `grid-column: 1` to place that div to the first row / column?

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/ypxm5g1s/2/
I want to item 12 sticky display first and item1 display second

Comment: you create multiple 'sticky' classes and adjust `grid-row` and `grid-column` definitions to *place* your divs randomly if that's what you intend to do

Comment: I created two class featured but first isn't show :/ https://jsfiddle.net/L42wctge/1/

Comment: yeah that's what happens - they will overlap as both are in the *same* row and *same* column... try [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property instead... see https://jsfiddle.net/3h76Lcyo/